# How to split up SGF key/value pairs like 'A[B][q]G[boy]'?

Tags: python, regex

In Python, I'm trying to split a string with SGF key/value pairs into a list or match object like so:

```
'A[B][q]G[boy]' --> ['A[B][q]', 'G[boy]']
```

(Keys are 'A' and 'G', values are '[B][q]' and '[boy]', respectively.)

I've tried splitting them up with this regex pattern

```
pattern = r'([A-Z]\[.+\])[A-Z]'
```

But this fails when there's only one key/value such as 'A[B]'

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://ideone.com/dAGz43

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your regex pattern seems to work for multiple key/value inputs like 'A[B][q]G[boy]' but didn't work on single ones like, 'A[B][q]'. Any thoughts?

Comment: In that case you could make the last part optional `([A-Z]\[[A-Z]\]\[[a-z]\])([A-Z]\[[a-z]+\])?` using a question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [**`re.finditer`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) function:

```
import re

def find_sgf_groups(s: str):
    sgf_groups = []
    for m in re.finditer(r'[A-Z](\[[a-zA-Z]+\])+', s):
        sgf_groups.append(m.group())

    return sgf_groups

print(find_sgf_groups('A[B][q]'))
print(find_sgf_groups('A[B][q]G[boy]'))
```

The output (sequentially):

```
['A[B][q]']
['A[B][q]', 'G[boy]']
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Didn't know re.finditer existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex for split based solution,

```
(?<=])(?=[A-Z])
```

**[Demo for split based](https://regex101.com/r/RnUfJY/1)**

Sample python code for split based solution,

```
import re

arr = ['A[B][q]G[boy]','A[B][q]']

for s in arr:
 splittedstr = re.split('(?<=])(?=[A-Z])', s)
 print(splittedstr)
```

Prints,

```
['A[B][q]', 'G[boy]']
['A[B][q]']
```

If you want match based solution, you can use this regex,

```
[A-Z](?:\[\w+])*
```

**[Demo for match based](https://regex101.com/r/5hsRSn/1)**

Sample python codes for match based solution,

```
import re

arr = ['A[B][q]G[boy]','A[B][q]']

for s in arr:
 print(re.findall(r'[A-Z](?:\[\w+])*',s))
```

Prints,

```
['A[B][q]', 'G[boy]']
['A[B][q]']
```

Use any that suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex does not match all the formats because `\[.+\]` and `[A-Z]` require a match. `.+` is also a greedy match and will match until the last occurence of `]`

You could use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=re%20findall#re.findall) and make the value between the first square brackets optional and repeat the last part 0+ times:

```
[A-Z](?:\[[A-Z]\])?(?:\[[a-z]+\])*
```

**Explanation**

- `[A-Z]` Match uppercase char
- `(?:\[[A-Z]\])?` Optional non capturing group that matches `[` uppercase char `]`
- `(?:\[[a-z]+\])*` Repeat 0+ times `[` 1+ lowercase chars `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cTeCJJ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Es1lJw)

Example

```
import re
strings = ["A[B][q]G[boy]", "A[B][q]", "A[B]"]
for s in strings:
    print(re.findall(r"[A-Z](?:\[[A-Z]\])?(?:\[[a-z]+\])*", s))
```

Result

```
['A[B][q]', 'G[boy]']
['A[B][q]']
['A[B]']
```

Note

If you want to match more than one uppercase chars you could use a quantifier `[A-Z]+` and you can adjust what you want to match in the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) accordingly.